# Scala - Load XML from file and override text values

Tags: xml, scala

I have an XML file with many tags that carry the same info, but are required by a service I'm trying to use.

```
<request>
    <first>{firstName}</first>
    <first_1>{firstName}</first_1>
    <first_2>{firstName</first_2>
</request>
```

In order to save time, I just want to be able to load the XML file and override all values in curly braces with the matching variable name such that:

```
val firstName = Bob
val myXML = XML.loadFile("path_to_file")
// TODO: myXML.override("firstName", firstName)
```

Would yield the XML:

```
<request>
    <first>Bob</first>
    <first_1>Bob</first_1>
    <first_2>Bob</first_2>
</request>
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example assuming that the variables can be stored in a standard Map.

For demonstration purposes, I added a "lastName" so there will be multiple variables.

Note that you can open and read the file into a variable such as `xml`, with `Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.mkString` or something equivalent.

Docs for [Map](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html) include the `foldLeft` method description, but in general, it can be used to repeatedly apply a function to an initial value (`xml` in this case), given a collection (`vars` in this case) which provides parameters to this function.

```
val vars = Map("firstName" -> "Sally", "lastName" -> "Dunn")
val xml = """<request>
    <first>{firstName}</first>
    <first_1>{firstName}</first_1>
    <last_2>{lastName}</last_2>
</request>"""

// entry is a Map entry (or Tuple)
vars.foldLeft(xml)((res, entry) => res.replace("{" + entry._1 + "}", entry._2))
```

Result:

```
<request>
    <first>Sally</first>
    <first_1>Sally</first_1>
    <last_2>Dunn</last_2>
</request>
```